# What is the maximum (and minimum) 16-bit double value?

Tags: c++, audio, double, wav

I am working on *audio data manipulation* (from/to `WAV` files, 16 bits), representing samples with `double` values (64 bits).

Since I am working with a lot of amplitude-domain convolution, a lot of time my resulting samples have (positive or negative ) values that go "above" the "maximum data" that can be represented on 16 bits, and the result is they get truncated.

So I need to **normalize** my data before writing it on a `WAV` file.

But it isn't clear to me what are the max (and minimum) `double` values that can be represented on 16 bits.

*notice: here I refer to ***minimum value*** as the maximum negative double number that can be represented in 16bits.*

*edit: with `16-bits double` I refer to data read from a 16 bit WAV file, stored in my code as a `double` value*. After amplitude convolution, this data occurs to become greater than 1 or less than -1.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo thanks for the answer, I need a clarification: How can I convert it again to `double` ? I will need double values to be written in the wav file. 
A simple `static_cast<double> result;` would work?

Comment: -32,768 to +32,767 is the range of a 16 bit signed integer. Putting this into a double should not change that. [https://ideone.com/ZnbKfR](https://ideone.com/ZnbKfR)

Comment: Here is a Wikipedia entry describing the bit layout for a 16-bit floating point:  [IEEE 16-bit floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that your denominator (for normalizing 16-bit data) is 2^15 assuming signed PCM.

Divide all your incoming 16-bit data by 32767 is my solution for normalizing. Maybe a case can be made for 32768, as the data ranges from -32768 to 32767. But I've always used 32767.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the maximum (and minimum) 16-bit double value?

It's unclear what you mean by "16-bit double".

There is a numeric type `double` in C++. It is a floating point type. The C++ language doesn't define its maximum or minimum representable values (although it does define a minium range, which the implementations may exceed), but it is possible to inspect those limits using `std::numeric_limits`.

However, on most systems, `double` is a 64 bit type, namely the "double precision" floating point type as specified in IEEE-754 standard.

---

A 16 bit type can represent at most 2<sup>16</sup> different values.

If used to represent an unsigned integer, the range will be [0, 2<sup>16</sup>).

If used to represent a signed integer, the range will depend on how the sign is represented. In the most common, 2's complement representation, the range will be [-2<sup>16-1</sup>, 2<sup>16-1</sup>)

> WAV files

In the Microsoft WAVE format, the 16 bit samples are 2's complement signed integers. See the previous paragraph for their value range.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify what I mean with 16-bit double.

Comment: Minor point: C++ (through C) **does** define the **minimum** required ranges of `float` and `double` types. Just as with integer types, these come in through the C macros that describe the types. So, for example, `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX`, and `LDBL_MAX` must be at least 1E+37.